# How can I change values of the `.ini` files via command line? (linux or windows)

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, php.ini

How can I change values of the `.ini` files via command line? (linux or windows)

For example I have a `php.ini` file:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Now, I need be like this command:

```
MAGIC-COMMAND display_errors=Off error_reporting=E_ALL php.ini
```

And that options effective and write in `php.ini` file, and I have this content:

```
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Comment: What have *you* tried? `sed -i` looks like a good start.

Comment: How about `vi php.ini` and then edit from Linux command line accordingly with vi? Are you trying to just get a method to edit in the command line or do you need to automate the task with a script or some command you can just run over and over?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski,  I don't need a find and replace software, I need to a smart setter and getter. be like this for parse: https://github.com/rudimeier/bash_ini_parser

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT see latest comment.

Comment: "I need to a smart setter and getter" -- Is your question asking for software recommendation then? (which would be off-topic here, so think twice). `sed` is perfectly capable of doing the changes your question describes. If you need something "smart" then please [edit] the question and explain your requirements. All this aside, my point was your question doesn't show your research effort. It's like "write a script for me" (off-topic, we're not a script writing service; we can help you with your *existing* script though) or "find a software for me" (off-topic). See [ask].